# Ecto + Elixir: How do I query a hashmap field?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a model:

```
defmodule VideoChat.User do
  use VideoChat.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :device_identifier, :string
    field :matches, :map

    timestamps()
  end

  ...
end
```

How would I look for all users with a "cool" key in their `matches` hash?

`User |> where([u], u.matches["cool"] != nil) |> limit(1) |> VideoChat.Repo.one`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:map` fields are stored as JSONB fields in PostgreSQL by Ecto. Ecto does not provide any functions to do map specific operations on such fields, but it can be done using `fragment` and custom SQL.

The SQL query `foo.bar ? 'baz'` will check if the column `bar` of `foo` contains a value in the key `"baz"`. This can be expressed with `fragment` like this:

```
fragment("? \\? ?", foo.bar, "baz")
```

So your code should be modified to:

```
User |> where([u], fragment("? \\? ?", u.matches, "cool")) |> limit(1) |> VideoChat.Repo.one
```

In a brand new `Map` model with key `map` of type `:map`:

```
iex(1)> Repo.insert! %MyApp.Map{map: %{}}
iex(2)> Repo.insert! %MyApp.Map{map: %{foo: 1}}
iex(3)> Repo.insert! %MyApp.Map{map: %{foo: 2}}
iex(4)> Repo.insert! %MyApp.Map{map: %{bar: 1}}
iex(5)> Repo.all MyApp.Map |> where([m], fragment("? \\? ?", m.map, "foo"))
[debug] QUERY OK source="maps" db=1.8ms decode=5.3ms
SELECT m0."id", m0."map", m0."inserted_at", m0."updated_at" FROM "maps" AS m0 WHERE (m0."map" ? 'foo') []
[%MyApp.Map{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "maps">, id: 2,
  inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-07 10:19:53>, map: %{"foo" => 1},
  updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-07 10:19:53>},
 %MyApp.Map{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "maps">, id: 3,
  inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-07 10:19:55>, map: %{"foo" => 2},
  updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-07 10:19:55>}]
iex(6)> Repo.all MyApp.Map |> where([m], fragment("? \\? ?", m.map, "bar"))
[debug] QUERY OK source="maps" db=2.9ms queue=0.2ms
SELECT m0."id", m0."map", m0."inserted_at", m0."updated_at" FROM "maps" AS m0 WHERE (m0."map" ? 'bar') []
[%MyApp.Map{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "maps">, id: 4,
  inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-07 10:19:59>, map: %{"bar" => 1},
  updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-07 10:19:59>}]
iex(7)> Repo.all MyApp.Map |> where([m], fragment("? \\? ?", m.map, "baz"))
[debug] QUERY OK source="maps" db=2.2ms queue=0.1ms
SELECT m0."id", m0."map", m0."inserted_at", m0."updated_at" FROM "maps" AS m0 WHERE (m0."map" ? 'baz') []
[]
```